How to configure app widget with SwiftData
I need to configure a widget by SwiftData object (in my case a TaskItem), so when the user selects a TaskItem the widget will provide him the chosen task info, to do that we need AppIntent which contains a parameter that conforms to AppEntity. I found some example code as shown bellow but it's not for SwiftData object, I need an example code to implement widget configuration with SwiftData.
The example code:
struct SelectTaskIntent: AppIntent, WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Select Coffee"
    static var description: IntentDescription = .init(stringLiteral: "Select a coffee")
    @Parameter(title: "Coffee") var task: Coffee
}

struct Coffee: Equatable, Hashable, AppEntity {
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "WidgetSelectionCoffees"
    
    typealias DefaultQueryType = CoffeeQuery
    static var defaultQuery: CoffeeQuery = CoffeeQuery()

    static var typeDisplayName: LocalizedStringResource = LocalizedStringResource("Coffee", defaultValue: "Coffee")
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: .init(stringLiteral: name))
    }

    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: URL
}

struct CoffeeQuery: EntityStringQuery {
    typealias Entity = Coffee
    func entities(matching string: String) async throws -> [Coffee] {
        return []
    }

    func entities(for identifiers: [UUID]) async throws -> [Coffee] {
        return [ ]
    }
}


I found some example code and to make the SwiftData model conform to AppEntity protocol, but I got an error from Xcode at compile time, the issue is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78765693/fix-error-when-make-swiftdata-model-conform-to-appentity-protocol

After hours of searching, I found the example code that helped me in the link Configurable Widgets: iOS
