Fix error when make SwiftData model conform to AppEntity Protocol
I tried to make a SwiftData model conform to AppEntity protocol to use it as a parameter in AppIntent, I got the example code from App Intent driven development in Swift and SwiftUI , but I got an error from Xcode at compile time, so I don't know what is the issue that cause this error and how can fix it?
The App Intent:
struct SelectTaskIntent: AppIntent, WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Select Task"
    static var description: IntentDescription = .init(stringLiteral: "Select a task")
    @Parameter(title: "Task") var task: TaskItem
}

The TaskItem code:
@Model
final class TaskItem {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    var text: String
    @Attribute(.unique) private (set) var id: UUID
    var section: SectionItem? // Relationship property
    
    // MARK: - Init
    init() {
        var text = ""
        id = UUID()
        section = nil 
    }
}

TaskItem + App Entity - Extension
extension TaskItem: AppEntity {
    
    static var defaultQuery = WidgetSelectionTasks()
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Widget Selection Tasks"
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(text)")
    }
}

struct WidgetSelectionTasks: EntityQuery {
    
    // Filter all available tasks using the given identifiers
    func entities(for identifiers: [UUID]) async throws -> [TaskItem] {
        return []
    }
    
    // Return a list of suggested tasks to use (important & urgent)
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [TaskItem] {
        
        return []
    }
    
    // Return default selected tasks
    func defaultResult() async -> TaskItem? {
        return nil
    }
}

the error


From the documentation, maybe an advice worth following? It is up to you whether you want to conform to the AppEntity protocol directly on the data models of your app, or if you create data models specific to your app intents implementation. In many cases, it’s a good idea to create models specific to app intents that shadow your app data models to keep entities separate from the rest of your app’s logic.
